# Erlang erlyberly build is failing

Tags: javafx, erlang, erlang-shell

Setup: Java 17.0.1, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, openjfx installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjfx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
.....

$ apt list --installed | grep fx

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

grub-gfxpayload-lists/jammy,now 0.7 amd64 [installed]
libmfx1/jammy,now 22.3.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libopenjfx-java/jammy,jammy,now 11.0.11+0-1 all [installed,automatic]
libopenjfx-jni/jammy,now 11.0.11+0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjfx-source/jammy,jammy,now 11.0.11+0-1 all [installed,automatic]
openjfx/jammy,now 11.0.11+0-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Reference: https://github.com/andytill/erlyberly/wiki/Compiling

I have git cloned as specified in the reference. When I try to build using "`./mvnw clean compile install assembly:single`", I am getting the following error. Please help me in resolving the issue.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[38,20] package javafx.event does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[39,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[40,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[41,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[42,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[43,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[44,26] package javafx.scene.input does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[45,26] package javafx.scene.input does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[46,26] package javafx.scene.input does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhuvan/git/erlyberly/src/main/java/erlyberly/TermTreeView.java:[49,35] cannot find symbol
```

Comment: the build scripts assume you are using oracle jdk 8 (which includes javafx). if you are going to compile with something else you must specify where the javafx modules are located

Comment: I have installed openjfx using "$ sudo apt-get install openjfx". The command "apt show openjfx" shows all details about the package except the folder where it is installed. How to find out the installation folder?

Comment: I have downloaded the JavaFx SDK from https://download2.gluonhq.com/openjfx/19.0.2.1/openjfx-19.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin-sdk.zip. After unzipping the file, I specified the JavaFx lib folder ~/bin/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib in the classpath inside the mvnw file. But, it did not resolve the problem "package javafx.event does not exist". What could be the issue?

Comment: The command "$ sudo apt-get install openjfx" has installed 11.0.11+0-1. Whereas, https://download2.gluonhq.com/openjfx/19.0.2.1/openjfx-19.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin-sdk.zip provides version 19.0.2.1. Which version of JavaFx is compatible for the JDK 17.0.1?

Comment: to compile with a different version you will need to edit the pom.xml specifying the relevant plugins as well. another option is to compile directly from the ide you use (you have to manually configure the project).

Comment: personally i recommend you to download java 8 on oracle. this way you will avoid all compilation (and subsequent app launch) problems.

Comment: Thanks @mrmcwolf for suggesting to install Java 8. It resolved the issue quickly.

Comment: I got the answer myself for my one of my earlier question on finding the installation folder of a package. We need to use `"dpkg -L openjfx"`